# ReactJS function is not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { obj: this.two }
    this.one = this.one.bind(this);
    this.two = this.two.bind(this);
  }

  one() {
    console.log("Working...")
  }

  two() {
    return <input type='submit' onClick={this.one} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
          As Function:<B two={this.two} />
          As Object Property: <B two={this.state.obj} />
      </h1>
    )
  }
}


class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.two()}</h1>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Here i am trying to send a function `two` from component A to component B which returns an input element.On input element i have given onClick which calls function `one` of component A and outputs in console.

So now i'm sending the function `two` to component B in two forms

- One as a direct function
- Other as a property of an object,which is given in state[as object property]

In both the cases button is rendering but the input is firing onClick only with the 1st case but not with 2nd
i want to make this work in 2nd case also.

Thanks in advance...Help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the easiest change would be to move the state assignment to the last line of your constructor, for the simple reason, that then the binding to the this context would work.

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.one = this.one.bind(this);
    this.two = this.two.bind(this);
    this.state = { obj: this.two };
  }
  // ... rest stays as is
}
```

When you are setting the `state` first, and only afterwards change the binding context, then the `state.obj` won't be context bound to the this.

And although this would be a solution to your problem as you presented it, I am unclear if this is what you really want. I strongly advise against creating child components in the way you did, it would make A way to powerfull, A should be the one deciding how B should be rendered.

Maybe you just want to pass a stateless component to your class B, that receives a callback function that should trigger on class A, which could/should be achieved by passing props, not by passing a method which renders another component.

So you could create something rather like

```
const SubmitButton = ({ 
  trigger = () => {}, 
  text = "Submit"
}) => <input type="Submit" onClick={trigger} value={text} />;
```

and then use it like in this example

```js
const SubmitButton = ({ 
  trigger = () => {}, 
  text = "Submit"
}) => <input type="Submit" onClick={trigger} value={text} />;

class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { obj: this.one }
  }

  one() {
    console.log("Working...")
  }

  two() {
    return <input type='submit' onClick={this.one} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
          <div>As Function:<SubmitButton trigger={() => this.one()} text="Submit Function" /></div>
          <div>As Object Property: <SubmitButton trigger={() => this.state.obj()} text="Submit state" /></div>
          <div>Through B function:<B itemTemplate={SubmitButton} trigger={() => this.one()} /></div>
          <div>Through B state:<B itemTemplate={SubmitButton} trigger={() => this.state.obj()} /></div>
      </h1>
    )
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Template = this.props.itemTemplate;
    return <h1><Template {...this.props} /></h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: I have tried it,But it's not working.Can you please implement in snippet and show me that

Comment: @Abhishek Yeah sorry, I added now the fix for your app to get it working, and another way to get more flexibility in your work ;)

Answer (score 0):

State is asynchronous in React. You cannot set a state and consume it immmediately. This applies to initial state set too.